# Methods to print ouput besides alert and document.write

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is some of the coding I have. I wanted to make the statements print directly on the page instead of using alert or document.write. I tried to use getElementId but it isnt working that great for me, I tried it on the first line in the script. The others are still an alert. Help?

```
<body>
<div id="myDiv1"></div>
<div id="myDiv2"></div>

Select one:<br>
<form name="locationform">
  <input type="checkbox" name="North">North <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="South">South<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Equator">Equator<hr>
Select another one:<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Inward">Inward<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Outward">Outward<br><br>

  <input type="button" value="Submit" name="myButton"     onClick="myfunction()">

<button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
</form>

<script language="JavaScript">


function myfunction() {
  ***if((document.locationform.North.checked == true) &&     (document.locationform.Inward.checked == true)){
    document.getElementById('myDiv1').innerhtml = 'Some Test';***

  }else if((document.locationform.South.checked == true) && (document.locationform.Outward.checked == true)){
    alert("Case 4.");

}else if((document.locationform.Equator.checked == true) && (document.locationform.Outward.checked == true)){
    alert("Case 6.");

}else if((document.locationform.South.checked == true) && (document.locationform.Inward.checked == true)){
    alert("Case 3.");

}else if((document.locationform.North.checked == true) && (document.locationform.Outward.checked == true)){
    alert("Case 5.");

}else if((document.locationform.Equator.checked == true) && (document.locationform.Inward.checked == true)){
    alert("Case 2.");


} else if((document.locationform.Inward.checked == false) && (document.locationform.Outward.checked == false)){       
    alert("Select a valid entry");


 } else if((document.locationform.North.checked == true) && (document.locationform.South.checked == true)){       
    alert("Select a valid entry");

  } else if((document.locationform.North.checked == true) && (document.locationform.Equator.checked == true)){       
    alert("Select a valid entry");

} else if((document.locationform.Equator.checked == true) && (document.locationform.South.checked == true)){       
    alert("Select a valid entry");

}

</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean  by "isnt working that great for me" and if `innerhtml` works, then why not use it?

Comment: I had a bug in the code, because it wouldn't print anything off.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug in your code

```
document.getElementById('myDiv1').innerhtml = 'Some Test';
```

should be

```
document.getElementById('myDiv1').innerHTML = 'Some Test';
```

Test it out in your console. `element.innerhtml` will return `undefined` because that is not a method.

Here's the source

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div id="write_here"></div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('write_here').innerHTML = 'Print Text Here';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `innerHTML` not `innerhtml`.

e.g. `document.getElementById('mainbar').innerHTML`